# CSS overflow boxes

Tags: css, overflow

I have a series of tag boxes that are displayed inline. They might exceed the width of the container. In this case, I would like them to create another "imagined" row as follow:

```
[friend][foe][enermy][love]
[hate][indifferent]
```

How can I achieve this effect?

My setting now somehow creates very strange behavior: a small part (and its background) of the box containing [hate] is actually on the first line, while the text of the box, and the background appears on a second line.

```
[friend][foe][enermy][love][]
[hate][indifferent]
```

I didn't do anything strange when define these tags:

```
.tag-label {
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 10.998px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 13px;
margin: 2px;
padding: 1px 4px 2px;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and here is the html. It's long to I remove some elements

```
<div id="content">
    <span class="tag-label">
      <a href="/searches/search_tags?search_type=Listing&amp;tag=search">search (1)</a>
    </span>
    <span class="tag-label">
      <a href="/searches/search_tags?search_type=Listing&amp;tag=text">text (1)</a>
    </span>
    <span class="tag-label">
      <a href="/searches/search_tags?search_type=Listing&amp;tag=cool">cool (1)</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML too?

Comment: That HTML doesn't match up with the CSS. Please double check.

Comment: I don't like to use inline-block as it works really funky on ie7-.

Comment: Thank you, brian. Sorry all I copied a custom version and not the effective one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you've posted I would assume it has to do with `span` elements being `display: inline` by default, and inline elements act that way when wrapped. Change your `.tag-label` styling to `display: inline-block`.

Also, your `.event-item` class isn't even used in your HTML and furthermore styling it with `display: inline-block` is completely unnecessary if you're also going to give it `width: 100%`. Assuming the element is a block one (like `div`) you can just leave it at `display: block` and it will automatically fill the width of its parent.

Anyway, `display: inline-block` on your `span`s should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, powerbuoy! It fixes the problem!

Answer (score -1):

Use `float:left`

```
.event-item .tag-label{
    float:left;
    background-color: #8F8A8A;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bF247/